# Blender weird beveling around loop

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to bevel a very simple model but its giving me strange results. I originally had beveled this edge fine before, but then I wanted to change its size so I deleted all the front vertices, then re-extruded the shape.

I've read some other posts about this issue and it seems like the general consensus is poor topology, but this shape has no duplicate vertices, and its in general very simple. Another suggestion people seem to mention is overlapping vertices, but again that is not the case here as I've merged all duplicates.

I could just recreate this part easily and it would probably work, but I'd really like to know whats causing this as its happening on other parts in my model as well. I guessing it has something to do with normals or scale but I'm not sure what to do about that.

Here is a blend file incase you want to open it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JXQwqjJDnxlDsPIBmOwQaLsYQFIjePXp/view?usp=sharing

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Recalculate your normals.

Comment: I think bevel and some other tools can give strange results if your object has uneven scaling. You could try applying the scale if that is the case. Also make sure your normals are all pointing in the same directions.